Apache 2.4 conditional doesn't match regexp
I'm trying to match a simple condition in apache virtual host to rewrite the original URL and redirect to the load balancer definition.
The condition should match against URL like
    "https://myhost.mydom.com/my-first-path.xyz/mypath-sec/other-things"
for the string
    "/my-first-path.xyz/mypath-sec" in the REQUEST_URI,
and rewrite it into
    "balancer://my-loadbalacer-definition/mypath/other-things" (removing the -sec part from mypath-sec)
This is the condition code:
<IF "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/my-first-path.xyz/mypath-sec#">
  RequestHeader set Host my-first-path.xyz
  RewriteRule ^/my-first-path.xyz/(.*)-.*(/.*)$ balancer://my-loadbalacer-definition/$1$2
</IF>

I've tried:

/my-first-path.xyz/mypath-sec (with this syntax apache wont restart or reload)
m#/my-first-path.xyz/mypath-sec#     (also tried with escape \ for . and /)
m#/my-first-path.xyz/mypath-sec.*#   (also tried with escape \ for . and /)
m#^/my-first-path.xyz/mypath-sec#    (also tried with escape \ for . and /)
m#^/my-first-path.xyz/mypath-sec.*#  (also tried with escape \ for . and /)

It should be quite linear and easy (also if I'm very noob in these apache things...) but there's no way to make it working, always I get the following error in error_log as if the REQUEST_URI match returns false
AH00128: File does not exist: /my-first-path/mypath-sec
Any idea ?
Thanks a lot in advance.
